# Why does my code only return every second result in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been writing some code which pulls entries from a MySQL database. These are numbers 1 to 38

However, it only returns every second number i.e. 2,4,6,8 instead of 1,2,3,4.

```
$result = mysql_query("select (caseID) FROM `case` order by caseID")
 or die(mysql_error());  

while(mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{ 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    $countName= $row['caseID'];

    Print $countName;
}
```

I've tried various changes and reducing the code to the bare minimum. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling mysql_fetch_array  two times, thats why.

Try this

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) 
{ 
$countName= $row['caseID'];
 print $countName;
}
```

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling `mysql_fetch_array`, which retrieves one result, and then you call `mysql_fetch_assoc`, which retrieves yet another result. That is then repeated until there are no more results left.

Or, in other words, you are fetching one result without using it, and then fetching another result which is then used, effectively jumping over every other result.

This should do the job:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
    print $row['caseID'];
}
```

Also, take a look at [the documentation](http://php.net/mysql_query). Turn your eyes to the big box that says "Warning" and has a stop sign in it.